# How to reduce label shape size on pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot, I did it with the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax=plt.axes()
ax.set_xlabel('Valencia', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel("Excitacion", fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Valor de la Emocion en modelo circumplejo')

labels=[]
N=50

for i in range(0,total_de_chunks):
    x=y=0
    data=modelado_lista_emociones_chunk_grafica[i]
    names = list(data.keys())
    values = list((data.values()))
    x = (data['Valence'])
    y = (data['Arousal'])
    
    labels.append(names[0])
    
    r = ((data[names[0]]*100)**2) # in points, not data units
    colors = np.random.rand(N)
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=r,  alpha=0.5,cmap='hsv')
    
ax.legend(loc=8,framealpha=1, fontsize=8)
plt.legend(labels, numpoints=10)

fig.show()
```

but, the part that shows the labels keeps the size of the scatter.
I have been trying to reduce them without success. I am only looking to display a small dot or square with the color and name, not the actual size.

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the variable `r`, because its the one that’s blowing up your dots according to the data. If you just don’t include the marker size parameter or `s` , the dots will be plotted on a default scale.

Comment: Thanks Max. It works, as it reduces the size of the markers within the labels, but it also reduce the size on the plot, something I want to keep.

Comment: Got it!
markerscale, on 
`ax.legend(loc=8,framealpha=1, fontsize=8 , markerscale=0.3)`